# Import a SCSS "exported" variable into the Javascript code within a .vue file that is loaded by vue-loader and bundled by webpack

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, sass, vue-loader

I have a variable in my `vars.scss` that I want to access from Javascript in `root/app/app.vue`.

**root/app/scss/vars.scss**

```
:export {
    cursor: #fff;
}
```

**root/app/app.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="yes">
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
import colors from '@/scss/vars.scss';

export default Vue.extend({
  mounted() {
    console.log(colors.cursor);
  },
});
</script>

<style >
</style>
```

I have read approximately 30 different stackoverflow questions that appear to be dealing with the similar problem of importing variables into the `style` block of the `.vue` file, as well as the identical problem of importing the variables directly into the Javascript code. As a result, my `webpack.config.js` looks like the following:

**root/webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin');
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV

module.exports = {
  entry: './app/index.ts',
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'staticfiles')
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.ts', '.js', '.vue', '.scss', '.sass'],
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, '/app/')
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin(),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new VueLoaderPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.(js|vue|ts)$/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
            // Since sass-loader (weirdly) has SCSS as its default parse mode, we map
            // the "scss" and "sass" values for the lang attribute to the right configs here.
            // other preprocessors should work out of the box, no loader config like this necessary.
            'scss': 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader',
            'sass': 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?indentedSyntax',
          }
          // other vue-loader options go here
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/],
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.s(a|c)ss$/,
        use: [ {
          loader: "style-loader",
          options: {
            sourceMap: env === 'development',
          }
        }, {
          loader: "css-loader",
          options: {
            sourceMap: env === 'development',
          }
        }, {
          loader: "sass-loader",
          options: {
            sourceMap: env === 'development',
          }
        },
        'vue-style-loader'],
      }]
  }
};
```

I have also tried, in the `test: /\.s(a|c)ss$/` section, to put `vue-style-loader` at the beginning of the array.

I have tried many combinations of filenames when attempting to import the `.scss` file, such as relative (`../scss/vars.scss`), removing the extension, using `.css` as an extension, etc.

The error I get is:

```
ERROR in /home/Documents/application/app/app.vue.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /home/Documents/application/app/app.vue.ts(10,28)
      TS2307: Cannot find module '@/scss/vars.scss'.
```

**My question:**

In a project that uses `vue-style-loader` and `vue-loader` to build `.vue` files with webpack, how can I import `.scss` variables into the `<script>` portion of a `.vue` file? (please note - I am NOT attempting to import them into the `<style>` section of the `.vue` file)

Comment: Why not simply define a CSS custom property (aka CSS variable) equal to the SCSS variable and then read that directly via `style.getProperty()`?

Comment: What you're trying to achieve should definitely work but it seems you just have an issue resolving the file.. Try with a relative path instead of absolute like `import colors from './scss/vars.scss';`

Answer (score 1):

An example based on my comment:

SCSS fragment:

```
$foo: #333;

body {
    --variable-foo: $foo;
}
```

And then anywhere in the JavaScript

```
const value = document.body.style.getPropertyValue("--variable-foo");
console.log(value); // outputs "#333"
```

Comment: I appreciate this - if I have to do it, I will. Ideally, though, I will be able to take advantage of the scss `export` functionality, so that my code "guarantees" the proper value (out of curiousity - what happens with this method if my client has a custom stylesheet that happens to have variables defined?)

Comment: CSS variables work just like any other property. Depends on the cascade, specificity, and order in which they're defined.